# Fixed height on tabs navigation widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Can someone please help me with finding out how to set my tabs widget to a set height, so when more content is added, it will then revert to a scrollbar to see more information. Currently it just keeps expanding as I add more content. I tried looking through the css and js and can't figure it out. I need to contain this widget so that my homepage does not expand for miles.

Here is the site I got the tabs widget from:
http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Here is the CSS file:
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your css

```
.elementclassname { 
height:800px; 
Overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce what you want in the same example of the page http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

you need to add this to your css:

```
#tabs-1, #tabs-2, #tabs-3 { 
height:200px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

You can take a look at it here https://jsfiddle.net/wallek876/cacn5djv/2/